Is it possible that some "stars" or "black holes" have "wormholes" in their center?
Seems like if the mass of a "star" or "black hole" changed without absorbing or expelling anything, then that would be an indicator that there is a "wormhole" inside.
Maybe some "stars" or "black holes" are formed like volcanoes along the 4D tectonic plates of the universe.

When has a black hole or star inexplicably changed in mass? This is dependent on theoretical situations that haven't been observed.

Somewhat related: Are wormholes even possible?

Seems like things like "stars" and "black holes" would be likely objects to exist at the openings of "wormholes", if they were to be built.  Maybe if there was a small opening, like 1 mile or so, the changes in mass would be nearly impossible to detect.

Wormholes are theoretical, we cannot determine the properties of an object that might not even exist. Is this a question, or are you proposing a theory?

You seem to think wormholes exist and are an inherent property of the universe? Most parts of the two questions you've asked read more like fiction than science, hence the downvotes. If you're serious about this you need to explain in more detail why you think stars and blackholes are somehow linked. It doesn't make sense to me.

There's a lot of theories about "wormholes".  I'm essentially saying that if there are anomalous fluctuations in the mass of "stars" or "black holes", that could be an indicator that "wormholes" exist.  I guess there's probably not any records of mass fluctuations occurring..  Nevertheless, if "wormholes" do exist, the inside or center of "stars" and "black holes" might be a good guess, especially considering the distortion effects "black holes" have on mass.

Does this answer your question? Are wormholes even possible?

So wormholes are one of the four exact answers to the Einstein Field Equations. If those equations are right, which so far they have been (mostly), then wormholes must exist somewhere. However, finding one inside a star is unlikely.
You are more likely to find support in theory if you look for white holes, not wormholes. White holes are also an exact solution to the Einstein Field Equations. What's more, there is a significant body of observational evidence that we have, in fact, found quite a few of them. I am specifically referring to what are known as "active galactic nuclei" ("AGN").
There are two types of AGN: Seyfert Galaxies and Quasars. Both types of galaxies periodically experience massive explosions in their centers and shoot out relativistic jets of gas from their north/south poles. The plurality opinion among astronomers is that AGN (and our own galaxy) have supermassive black holes at the center, and that the explosions are the result of gravitational pressures exerted on infalling gas. However, this is just a plurality opinion and the idea that AGN are actually white holes has been discussed at length in the academic literaure.

"then wormholes must exist somewhere." Not necessarily. The equations permit wormholes, but you still need some mechanism to produce the wormhole. Also, a wormhole would probably be unstable, unless supported by "exotic matter" with negative mass. And there's no empirical evidence for such exotic matter, or any theoretical basis for it in the Standard Model of particle physics.
